# Pascal - Class inheritance between two different files?

Tags: pascal, lazarus, freepascal, delphi

Say I have two files, `characters.pas` and `ogre.pas`. An ogre is a character, but I'm trying to separate the two files for cleanliness sake. In `characters.pas` I have

```
unit Characters;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface
type
  TCharacter = class(TOBject)
    private
      // ...
    public
      // ...
    published
      // ...
  end;

implementation
  // Method bodies
end.
```

In `ogre.pas` I have

```
unit Ogre;

{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface
type
  TOgre = class(TCharacter)
    public
        constructor create; override;
    end;


implementation

constructor TOgre.create();
begin
  // Banana banana banana
end;
end.
```

Adding a `uses` block anywhere in either of the .pas files throws an error, which leads me to believe that all classes that rely on inheritance must be in the same file as their parents. Am I missing something?

Comment: _Adding a uses block anywhere in either of the .pas files throws an error_ It would be nice to see those code and error details. However @Nestedtype already answered to you question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you miss something: the `use` section. You have to declare that `unit Ogre` uses `unit Characters`:

unit Ogre;

```
{$mode objfpc}{$H+}

interface

uses
  Characters;

type
  TOgre = class(TCharacter)
    public
        constructor create; override;
    end;


implementation

constructor TOgre.create();
begin
  // Banana banana banana
end;
end.
```

read more:

- [unit example @FPC](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Unit#Detailed_unit_example)
- [the use of a second form @FPC wiki](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Form_Tutorial#The_Use_of_a_Second_Form)

Also note that if you want some fields to be visible from a `TCharacter` to a `TOgre` but still not accessible from the main program then you'll have to set their visibility to `protected`

Comment: For some strange reason the uses field has started working, although formerly it would cause the compiler to throw an error. Thank you very much for your help!